# KnockoutJS not updating the dom - interacting with Googlemaps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutJS for my udacity course and I can't seem to update part of my DOM.

I'm interacting with the google maps API. I have an observableArray that contains objects of locations with a bit of content as well as a "show" element that contains a value of true or false.
Now the observableArray is updating (it's based on whether or not the marker is within the bounds of the visible map) but it's not updating my DOM where it's only supposed to list the markers title of the locations that are visible.

```
this.locations = ko.observableArray([{
                title: 'Camden Brookwood',
                location: {
                    lat: 33.8027355,
                    lng: -84.3973864
                },
                content: "Camden Brookwood, Rank: 1",
                show: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Monroe Place',
                location: {
                    lat: 33.8092084,
                    lng: -84.370107
                },
                content: "Monroe Place, Rank: 2",
                show: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Capitol Gateway',
                location: {
                    lat: 33.7453517,
                    lng: -84.384106
                },
                content: "Capitol Gateway, Rank: 3",
                show: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Gables 820 West',
                location: {
                    lat: 33.7808463,
                    lng: -84.4162514
                },
                content: "Gables 820 West, Rank: 4",
                show: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Montage Embry Hills',
                location: {
                    lat: 33.8827244,
                    lng: -84.2480548
                },
                content: "Montage Embry Hills, Rank: 5",
                show: true
            }
        ]);
```

Here is what updates these values

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < locations().length; i++) {
        if(map.getBounds().contains(locations()[i].location))
        locations()[i].show = true;
        else {
          locations()[i].show = false;
        }
      }
  });
```

Here is the code for the relevant section for the DOM

```
<div data-bind="foreach: locations">
      <div class="mini-container" data-bind="visible: show">
        <div data-bind="text: show"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've also tried using the "if" data-bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show` property in each of your objects needs to be observable, i.e.

```
ko.observableArray([{
  title: 'Camden Brookwood',
  location: {
    lat: 33.8027355,
    lng: -84.3973864
  },
  content: "Camden Brookwood, Rank: 1",
  show: ko.observable(true)
}])
```

and then update it using

```
locations()[i].show(false)
```

As noted by the docs...

"Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects

Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed."

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Answer (score 1):

What you have is close to working, you'll have to make sure to bind the marker's `show` property to the `foreach` or whatever you use on the dom.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timh06/659zp473/

Basically, I converted your lat lng to google maps LatLng objects, and fixed up the knockout bindings.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: locations">
  <!-- ko if: show -->
  <h3 data-bind="text: content"></h3>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
// add markers
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vm.locations().length; i++) {
    var loc = vm.locations()[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc.location,
        map: map,
        visible: loc.show,
        title: loc.title
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.locations().length; i++) {
        var marker = vm.locations()[i];
        if (bounds.contains(marker.location)) {
            marker.show(true);
        } else {
            marker.show(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh no this isn't what I'm trying to do.
I have a list to the left of the map that I want to show the name's of the locations of the markers in a list.